# What is http://extras.ubuntu.com/ repository for?

Tags: development, repository, application-development, application-submission

What will this repository hold? What is policy for it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Starting with Ubuntu 10.10, it's set to host new applications that aren't in the repositories at the time of release. The process and implementation are [documented](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppReviews) on the wiki.

Comment: I've heard it will be available also for Ubuntu 10.04 LTS, but I did not fine any recent mention of that. Do you have information on this too?