# How do I enable the "extras" repository?

Tags: package-management, software-center, software-sources

I [keep reading](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/02/suspended-sentence-becomes-first-post-release-app-to-land-in-ubuntu/) about an [extras repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8570/what-is-http-extras-ubuntu-com-repository-for) for Ubuntu with new software that comes out independently of the distro release. How do I enable it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This repository should be enabled by default and is only available for 10.10 and up.

## Ubuntu Desktop

In the Software Center (Applications -> Ubuntu Software Center) navigate to Edit -> Software Sources...

[image: software sources]

From there navigate to the Other Software tab and ensure the Independent sources are selected

[image: independent]

Press close and allow the sources to reload.

## Ubuntu Server

Open the APT Sources list

```
sudoedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Locate the lines which say

[image: deb]

Remove the hash (`#`) tag from those lines. If the hashes are not present then that source is already enabled. If those lines aren't there at all you will need to add them to the bottom of the file:

```
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
```

Close the editor and run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

This will download the package cache from the extra's location.

Reference:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppReviews

Comment: explained like a pro, for newbies ;)