# Why Ubuntu accept paid apps after release?

Tags: software-center, paid-applications

If I'm right in Ubuntu "normal" apps should be inserted in official repository before the final release and after taht your apps will be included in next cycle.

But in these days I'm seeing that paid apps are included also after the final release, the last one some days ago.

Why does canonical accept paid apps but not free/opensource apps after final release?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are accepting applications after releases for both commercial and free applications starting with 10.10 using the [Ubuntu Extras Repository](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/09/new-ubuntu-extras-repository-is-now.html) Which is full of software released post version release.

For further reading I would suggest [How do I enable the "extras" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25692/how-do-i-enable-the-extras-repository)